# Spring @EventListener with two arguments

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-4, event-sourcing

I'm looking for a way to pass two arguments to an `@EventListener`. I have an `Event` class. It looks like this:

```
public class Event {
    String id;
    Date timestamp;
    String data;
    String type;
}
```

The `data` is serialized, and the type describes how to deserialize it.

Currently, I deserialize the event data, and then publish the deserialized `EventData` subclass instance on via an `ApplicationEventPublisher like so:

```
public void listen(Event event) throws IOException {
    EventData eventData = converter.toEventData(event);
    eventPublisher.publishEvent(eventData);        
}
```

This has worked well so far, but now I need access to both the event and the data in my listeners. Is there a way to pass two arguments to an `@EventListener`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't thing there is a way you could pass a second argument to event listeners.

You could add an `event` property to the `EventData` base class that is populated by the `converter` with the original argument that is passed to it.

Comment: What about using a tuple? I'm not current with java, but is there a tuple class that everyone uses?

Comment: @JoshC. I thought that the event-dispatching is done by the class of the `EventData` so that should remain the same. I suppose that if you can/would modify all your listeners then you could use a tuple.

Comment: What is the typical tuple class?

Comment: Actually, I realized the problem is I need to dynamically create the tuple. EventData is the super class, but I need to broadcast the derived type to ensure delivery to the right handler. The tuple would need to be instantiated with that derived type. I think I'm going with the back reference on the EventData class...